# How to use cocoa progress bars?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, progress-bar

I am a brand new Mac programmer and I need help on how to use `NSProgressIndicator`. I already looked for sample code, but couldn't find anything that helped.

What I want to do is this:

```
-(IBAction)startProgressBar:(id)sender; {

    //I want to make the bar update itself by the  value of 1 until it is at the value of 100
    //Example: add 1 to bar every second until it is full

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` will help you here.

Write a method that will increment your progress bar. At the end of that method call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` on the same method with a delay of 1 second until the bar is full.

You probably won't need to pass an object to that method, so you can just use nil.

**EDIT**

In your case I would recommend something like this:

```
- (IBAction)startProgressBar:(id)sender
{
    // Initialize the progress bar to go from 0 to 100
    [progress setMinValue:0.0];
    [progress setMaxValue:100.0];
    [progress setDoubleValue:0.0];

    // Start the auto-increment calls
    [self incrementProgressBar];
}

- (void)incrementProgressBar
{
    // Increment the progress bar value by 1
    [progress incrementBy:1.0];

    // If the progress bar hasn't reached 100 yet, then wait a second and call again
    if([progress doubleValue] < 100.0)
        [self performSelector:@selector(incrementProgressBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

Comment: I already know that line of code but I don't know how to LOOP it please give me more detail :)

Comment: Imagine you write a method with that line of code at the end. After the method is run, it will run again (after a delay). And again. It is kind of like a recursive method.

Comment: Yes but I want to make it loop until the bar is 100% full THEN I want to stop the loop please help :D

Comment: `NSProgressIndicator` has a selector `doubleValue` which returns its current value and another selector `maxValue` which returns its maximum value - its 100% value. After each increment, test whether `[progress doubleValue]` is less than `[progress maxValue]`. If not, then do not increment again - you are done!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to 'increment' sorry but I am just brand new :(

Comment: Incrementing an `NSProgressIndicator` is as simple as `[progress incrementBy:delta]` where `delta` is a double representing the amount to increment by. See my edit for example code.