# How to slowly fill the NSProgressIndicator (Progress Bar) from 0 to 100?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

**Task**:
Take Progress bar (NSProgressIndicator) from 0 to 100 smoothly.

**Problem**: 
Progress bar is getting 0 to 100 but not smoothly.

**What I have done as yet:**

```
    // scan click on which the prgress should start
-(void)ScanNowClick:(id)sender
{
        // setting initial value of progress bar
        [progressbar setDoubleValue:0];
        // starting timer
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(callAfter10sec:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];  
}

// timer that will update progress bar
-(void)callAfter10sec:(NSTimer *)time {

    double value = [progressbar doubleValue]+10;

    [[progressbar animator] setDoubleValue:value];

    if(value >= 100)
    {
       [time invalidate];
    }
}
```

/// layer is also set

[image]

Comment: Increase time interval to eg 0.05 and decrease the value you're adding (`10` in your example) or set an `UIView animateWithDuration...` and change the value inside the block.

Comment: it is possible to do it without timer?

Comment: Looks like an old question and a good answer:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470113/how-to-use-cocoa-progress-bars

Comment: @VikasBansal Did you try to do it via animation? Is it not working?

Comment: @Vive I have tried by animator. My way is given in the question. Please let me know how to do it by animation. Thankyou

Comment: @HeinrichGiesen, nice post. It would be a cherry on the cake if I could decide the time that progress bar will take to complete e.g 10 seconds or 1 minute.

Comment: @VikasBansal I'd downvote my own answer if I could. I didn't notice you're talking about OS X control, I've thought you've meant some custom iOS control (btw it would be handy if you add proper tag to the question), thats why I've talked about `UIView` and `animateWithDuration` method, which is available for iOS but not for OS X (as far as I see).

Comment: Here is a nice and short implementation of your problem: https://github.com/eternalstorms/NSProgressIndicator-ESSProgressIndicatorCategory. Hope that helps =)

Comment: @Vive I have gone through the project and hahaha... I am unable to understand the code. Its working fluently however I am just a beginner :(

Comment: @VikasBansal Great :) I'd just use this library in the project via cocoapods or as an submodule instead of re-typing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CADisplayLink` and not `NSTimer` when dealing with UI related updates.

The link is called 60 times per second (per the refresh rate of the screen)

In the callback you should calculate the proportion to advance the view

Comment: how to use CADisplayLink?

Comment: I see that you are using AppKit, which I don't know, but in iOS you create a CADisplayLink exactly like an NSTimer, but this is coordinated with the refresh of the screen which will ensure that any UI updates are coordinated